# Monotonic operators in classical logic

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Which means  monotony for a logical operator, and affinity, in propositional calculus affinity..., *[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)*  on wiki do not quite understand!!

Comment: *Monotonicity* is defined as : "a property of many logic systems that states that the hypotheses of any derived fact may be freely extended with additional assumptions". This means that in a logical system with this property (the "usual" systems are so) we have that : if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$, then also : $\Gamma \cup \{ \psi \} \vdash \varphi$.

Comment: As would in a context of boolean algebra. For example i've f(x1,...xn)<=f(y1,...yn) iff x1<=y1, ectc.. just, or not?

Comment: See [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) : "All laws with only conjunction and disjunction have the property that changing either argument either leaves the output unchanged or the output changes in the same way as the input. Equivalently, changing any variable from $0$ to $1$ never results in the output changing from $1$ to $0$. Operations with this property are said to be *monotone*. Nonmonotonicity enters via complement."